# Python selenium checkbox click does not work

Tags: python, selenium, checkbox

Hey im using python selenium to download data from table. But when im want to prepare data i cant select a checkbox 'toggle all'....

im geting on page:

```
browser.get("https://gold.jgi.doe.gov/studies?setColumns=yes&Organism.NCBI+Taxonomy+ID=%3D500633")
```

click 'select columns for table'

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="showColsButton"]').click()
```

and here we are checkbox ;toggle all'...

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="selectFieldsList"]/thead/tr[2]/td/input').click()
```

Realy tryed xpath, css selector....

and here we are html fragment:

```
<table class="selectFieldsList" id="selectFieldsList">

<thead>
        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
        Select Fields using the Checkboxes<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="fieldSubmit" id="submitMe" class="submitMe">
    </td></tr>


 <!--  add a select all option -->
       <script language="JavaScript">
       function toggle(source) {
           checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('selectField');
           for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
              checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
           }
       }

       </script>
       <tr><td> <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)"> Toggle All<br> </td></tr>
<tr><td>* = required column</td><td>&nbsp;</td> </tr>

<tr><td> <input type="button" id="entityFieldSelectorToggle" value="Expand All Fields"> </td>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
```

Comment: What version of python? What version of Selenium bindings?

Comment: python 3.5 and selenium 3.0.2

Comment: Hmm, I'm using OS X (10.11.6), Python 3.6, Selenium 3.3.1, and geckodriver to instantiate a Firefox (51.0.1 64-bit) browser window. When I run your code, the "Toggle All" box is checked. Is that the desired effect of the code?

Comment: I will check the software ;p

Comment: ok i solved it xD, I give 5 seconds sleep and it work :)

Comment: Ah yes, good old `sleep` :P Glad it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using sleep use explicit wait is good practise, because it will same 5 sec of time even after element is found. Hope it will be useful to you

```
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    driver.get("https://gold.jgi.doe.gov/studies?setColumns=yes&Organism.NCBI+Taxonomy+ID=%3D500633")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="showColsButton"]').click()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="selectFieldsList"]/thead/tr[2]/td/input')))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="selectFieldsList"]/thead/tr[2]/td/input').click()
```